# How to understand and debug from a VirtualBox log file?

Tags: c++, debugging, operating-system, virtualbox

I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rnA6wpF0o4&list=PLHh55M_Kq4OApWScZyPl5HhgsTJS9MZ6M) for developing an operating system. I am using Windows 10 as my host sytem and used wsl for compiling. But my VM fails as soon as I enable interrupts.

[This is the log file](https://github.com/ravi1997/code/blob/master/VM%20log) of the VM that is output, but I cannot understand it. I am pretty naive with VirtualBox. Can someone explain any possible error you see?

[Here is the code](https://github.com/ravi1997/myos.git) of the Os. I just have changed the structure I believe. Rest code in execution point of view is same as shown in video series.

Answer (score 2):

That is a lot of log to scroll through and it's hard to be sure on the face of it that just looking at that would be able to tell us what about your startup code (not visible to us as part of the question) would trigger it.  However, I can speak to some general strategies about approaching a log file like this.

We can see some general state transitions in there.  The log ends with:

```
00:00:15.712045 Changing the VM state from 'DESTROYING' to 'TERMINATED'
```

So I can go back through and look at where the first instance of `DESTROYING` showed up, which was:

```
00:00:15.698320 Changing the VM state from 'POWERING_OFF' to 'OFF'
00:00:15.701802 Changing the VM state from 'OFF' to 'DESTROYING'
```

Following the same process backwards to `POWERING_OFF`, I see:

```
00:00:08.577363 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
00:00:14.342287 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE (0x80bb0002) aIID={872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed} aComponent={ConsoleWrap} aText={Invalid machine state GuruMeditation when checking if the guest entered the ACPI mode)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:15.643579 GUI: Request for close-action to power VM off.
00:00:15.643599 GUI: Passing request to power VM off from machine-logic to UI session.
00:00:15.643606 GUI: Powering VM down on UI session power off request...
00:00:15.644257 Console: Machine state changed to 'Stopping'
00:00:15.644763 Console::powerDown(): A request to power off the VM has been issued (mMachineState=Stopping, InUninit=0)
00:00:15.645075 Changing the VM state from 'GURU_MEDITATION' to 'POWERING_OFF'
```

That error line at the top of that block may point to something searchable that would turn up other instances of people having the same or a similar problem.  If you scroll up a bit, you can also see that something VGA-related was happening right before the error, which may help narrow it down if it's directly related to the error, or may be another step to backtrack through on the way to the real issue.

Comment: Thanks for quick response yes it is a long log but I don't think I have enabled apci you can even look into my code I have shared the link

Comment: please can you look to code and tell me if you see any error